# one-hot encoding single sample pandas

Tags: python, pandas, encoding

**Problem statement:** I want to one-hot encode this single sample:

```
In [2]: single_sample = pd.DataFrame({"Color":['Green']})

             Color 
0            'Green'
```

with the same one-hot encoding used for this dataframe:

```
In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame({"Color":['Red', 'Blue', 'Green', 'Orange']})

             Color 
0            'Red'         
1            'Blue'     
2            'Green'       
3            'Orange'
```

After applying the one-hot encoding, the large dataframe would look like;

```
In [4]: pd.get_dummies(df)

      Color_Blue  Color_Green  Color_Orange  Color_Red
0              0            0             0          1
1              1            0             0          0
2              0            1             0          0
3              0            0             1          0
```

And I would want the single sample to be;

```
      Color_Blue  Color_Green  Color_Orange  Color_Red
0              0            1             0          0
```

The only way I thought of achieving this is to concatenate the single sample to the dataframe and preform the one-hot encoding operation afterwards or writing my own one-hot encoder which I could apply to the given columns.

Is there a better way to somehow save the operation the .get_dummies() function applies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) of columns by columns of `df1`:

```
df1 = pd.get_dummies(df)
print (df1)
   Color_Blue  Color_Green  Color_Orange  Color_Red
0           0            0             0          1
1           1            0             0          0
2           0            1             0          0
3           0            0             1          0

print (pd.get_dummies(single_sample).reindex(columns=df1.columns, fill_value=0))
   Color_Blue  Color_Green  Color_Orange  Color_Red
0           0            1             0          0
```

Another possible solution is create new columns by `list comprehension`:

```
cols = ('Color_' + df.Color.sort_values()).unique().tolist()
print (cols)
['Color_Blue', 'Color_Green', 'Color_Orange', 'Color_Red']

print (pd.get_dummies(single_sample).reindex(columns=cols, fill_value=0))
   Color_Blue  Color_Green  Color_Orange  Color_Red
0           0            1             0          0
```